# FNRPE2131090055E: Invalid ascii string for work object number:

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet, filenet-process-engine

I am using IBM Filenet Content Platform **5.2.1**
and recently I keep getting the following Process Engine error:

```
[FNRPE2131090055E]Invalid ascii string for work object number: "B1826D83A9FA7D****************FF".

    at filenet.jpe.base.Guid.<init>(Guid.java:111)
    at filenet.jpe.rpc.ejb.EJBPEUtils.getTypedArrayFromAPIArray(EJBPEUtils.java:1002)
    at filenet.jpe.rpc.ejb.EJB_rpc_fetchCount.execute(EJB_rpc_fetchCount.java:339)
    at filenet.jpe.rpc.ejb.PECommandsRemote.pejb_fetchCount(PECommandsRemote.java:980)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor67.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at filenet.jpe.rpc.ejb.PECommandsRemote.invokeRPC(PECommandsRemote.java:178)
    at filenet.jpe.rpc.ejb.PESendCommandImpl.invokeRPC(PESendCommandImpl.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor60.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.invokeProceed(EJSContainer.java:5730)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:568)
    at filenet.jpe.rpc.common.RequestInterceptor.getMyUser(RequestInterceptor.java:93)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor58.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InterceptorProxy.invokeInterceptor(InterceptorProxy.java:227)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:548)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.doAroundInvoke(InvocationContextImpl.java:229)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.invoke(EJSContainer.java:5621)
    at filenet.vw.server.rpc.EJSLocal0SLFNP8PESNDCMD_b55fe6a6.invokeRPC(EJSLocal0SLFNP8PESNDCMD_b55fe6a6.java)
    at filenet.jpe.rpc.ejb.PESendAPIRPCImpl.invokeRPC(PESendAPIRPCImpl.java:308)
    at filenet.jpe.rpc.ejb.PESendAPIRPCImpl.sendCommand(PESendAPIRPCImpl.java:207)
    at filenet.jpe.rpc.ejb.PESendAPIRPCImpl.sendCommandBytes(PESendAPIRPCImpl.java:159)
    at filenet.vw.server.rpc.EJSRemote0SLPESENDAPIRPC_7f999854.sendCommandBytes(EJSRemote0SLPESENDAPIRPC_7f999854.java)
    at filenet.vw.server.rpc._EJSRemote0SLPESENDAPIRPC_7f999854_Tie.sendCommandBytes(_EJSRemote0SLPESENDAPIRPC_7f999854_Tie.java:1)
    at filenet.vw.server.rpc._EJSRemote0SLPESENDAPIRPC_7f999854_Tie._invoke(_EJSRemote0SLPESENDAPIRPC_7f999854_Tie.java)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatchInvokeHandler(ServerDelegate.java:631)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatch(ServerDelegate.java:501)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:623)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:1581)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doRequestWork(Connection.java:3151)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doWork(Connection.java:3016)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.WorkUnitImpl.doWork(WorkUnitImpl.java:63)
    at com.ibm.ws.giop.threadpool.WorkQueueElement.dispatch(WorkQueueElement.java:174)
    at com.ibm.ws.giop.filter.GiopFilterChain.processMessage(GiopFilterChain.java:203)
    at com.ibm.ws.giop.threadpool.PooledThread.handleRequest(PooledThread.java:81)
    at com.ibm.ws.giop.threadpool.PooledThread.run(PooledThread.java:102)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1865)
```

Does anyone have any ideas why I'm getting this error and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PJ36242) an older solution to an issue calling the API that seems to be very similar to your case.

The proposed fix was to upgrade to the latest Process Engine fix pack, so I would recommend you to upgrade your system to the latest FileNet Content Engine Platform 5.2.1 FP3

Comment: i read this ibm article before posting the question, and i am not using the api in wrong way like in the article